# Angular 5 app deployment - Component URL routing not working in S3

Tags: angular

I have built my angular app using `ng build --prod` and copied the contents of the `dist` folder to an S3 bucket. The app works fine if I point my browser to `http://abc.xyz.com`. The links inside the app work too if navigating inside the app. Ex: `http://abc.xyz.com/information`

However, If I copy the URL to a component Ex: `http://abc.xyz.com/information` and enter it in the address bar, I get a 404 error. Why is the routing not working, using this way and how do I fix it? I am not sure what web server Amazon uses to serve an angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey take a look at https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml this explains the behavior and solves the problem. The angular app handles the routes defined inside your webapp. If you try to navigate to that path in your filesystem there won't be a file and your server doesn't know where to look.

Comment: okay, Thanks. I am trying to navigate to a path which is an existing component and route defined in Angular router. But yeah, in prod mode, there is no folder like that in the "dist" folder. Is there a way to go to index.html, but somehow route back to the component? I will be sharing links in angular app through an email and want the users to go that link.

Comment: Yes it is explained in the link for apache, nginx, iis and firebase. ng serve should do that automatically.

Comment: The documentation says, to route 404s to index.html. But how does it know which component path was requested and how to redirect to the component path from index.html? The documentation does not address that.

Comment: I think the information is given in the request... And the index.html knows what to do because that is your angular app which knows the route. I've never used S3 and didn't see it in your question at first but there is plenty of information and solutions.

Comment: You have to use cloudfront along with S3 to access sub urls/routes directly. Please follow as specified in this article. https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef

Comment: Thank you. This helped me resolve the issue in AWS.